# How to remove duplicates in a list while keeping elements with highest scores among duplicates, in C# with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Consider a list of the following class:

```
class A
{
    string Id;
    string FamilyId
    int Score
}
```

I would like to process the list so that elements with duplicate FamilyId fields are reduced to a single instance in the list; when eliminating duplicates, the highest score is the one I would like to retain.

For example, if I have the elements:

>

> ID, Family, Score
>
> 1,      A, 0
>
> 2,      B, 2
>
> 3,      B, 3

The final list should be:

> ID, Family, Score
>
> 1,      A, 0
>
> 3,      B, 3

I thought about sorting the list in bins by family and then keeping only the first element of each bin but I do not know how to make a LinQ implementation of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GroupBy`, `OrderByDescending` and `First` are your friends:

```
list = list.GroupBy(x => x.FamilyId)
           .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).First())
           .ToList();
```

Note that this will take an arbitrary first in case there are multiple with a max-score.

Comment: Can't you replace g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).First() by g.Max(x => x.Score) ?

Comment: @EldritchConundrum No, because that selects the max-value but you need the complete object with the max-score

Comment: Oh, right. I was thinking of MaxBy(), but it's part of my own extensions, not Linq's...

Comment: @EldritchConundrum yes, that's morelinq

Answer (score 0):

```
            List<A> myList = getYourListForWhereEver();
            var filteredList = new List<A>();
            foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                var existing = filteredList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.familyId == item.familyId);
                if (existing == null)
                {

                    // family is unique so add it
                    filteredList.Add(item);

                }
                else
                {
                    // check the score and replace if score is lower
                    if (existing.Score < item.Score)
                    {
                        filteredList.Remove(existing);
                        filteredList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The above will build a filtered list (Please do not copy paste as it can have typos). 
Basically go through all existing family scores. Add score to the filtered list if it does not exist yet, if it exists check the score and replace the value;

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the solution @TimSchmelter provided, but you can also use the result selector of the `GroupBy`:

```
var sortedGrouped = list.GroupBy(k => k.FamilyId, 
                                (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Score).First());
```